# DateTime.TryParseExact returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to get the `DateTime` format using `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
DateTime logDate;

DateTime.TryParseExact(
    string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", day, month, ddlYear.SelectedValue),
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out logDate);
```

it is returning `false`. am i missing something?

e.g. day=01, month=02, year= 2013

Comment: What is the result of `string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", day, month, ddlYear.SelectedValue)`?

Comment: share your `day`,`month` and `ddlYear.SelectedValue`

Comment: Arshad please see the edited post.

Comment: I would recommend to put it in Universal Format i.e. Year-Month-Day e.g. 2013-02-01, try to always use Universal Format with DateTimes, you will save your time with Globalisation issues

Comment: Not sure why it is returing false to you!! I am getting the date without any issues with your code :
            DateTime.TryParseExact(
                string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "01", "02", "2013"),
                "dd/MM/yyyy",
                null,
                System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                out logDate);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what's the problem, but you should try specifying `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` as `DateTime.TryParseExact` parameter:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    "20/12/2013",
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out logDate);
```

That's because `/` has special meaning within your pattern string:

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate localized date separator is retrieved from the `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property of the current or specified culture.
>
> *from Custom Date and Time Format Strings: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)*

There is a chance that the culture you're running your application in has date separator different then `/` itself.

Comment: Maybe becasue I using a culture with / and it's returning True not False

Answer (score 1):

I guess the day and month are of type `int` and hence the resultant is not recognized, so better off using `d/M/yyyy` format.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", day, month, ddlYear.SelectedValue),
    "d/M/yyyy",
    null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out logDate);
```

your string should come out as `"1/2/2013"`

> [The format of the string representation must match the specified
>   format
>   exactly.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)